# Passing COM objects as references within module

Tags: c++, com

Is there any reason or convention for not passing COM objects as references to internal functions?

I know that references cannot be used in COM API since that would break binary compatibility. But what about within a module?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly OK to pass COM objects by reference to non-COM functions. Even though a reference is just an alias to an object they are typically implemented as pointers under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

The question is fishy, the distinction between objects and interfaces is important in COM.  Client code that uses a COM server only ever works with interface pointers.  CoCreateInstance() creates an object *on the server* and returns an interface pointer to one of the interfaces implemented by the coclass.  Like IUnknown*.  At no point are you ever handling an object.  Boilerplate is to leave interface pointers as just pointers and passing them by reference isn't very useful.  You could wrap them in a smart pointer class so the Release() call is automatic.  Passing that smart pointer object by reference is fine, it doesn't have anything to do with COM.

It could be different in a COM server.  You typically implement an object there with a C++ class that implements the COM interfaces.  If code in that server needs a reference to that object then it makes sense to just pass a reference to the C++ object.  That's just standard usage of references in C++ and doesn't have anything to do with COM.